# Connection pooling for Sitecore 6

Tags: sql-server, sitecore, sitecore6

I was wondering if anyone knows how to set up connection pooling for Sitecore 6 running on SQLServer 2005 ?

And is this a good idea to setup on a Sitecore solution? Or probably more correct, will there be any problems if setup incorrectly?

Any other comments or tips about this are also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers from Sitecores support:

> By default, connection pooling is
>   enabled in ADO.NET (it means that we
>   don't need any connection string
>   parameters to enable it, parameters
>   are needed only to disable or to tune
>   the connection pooling). Thats why
>   there are no connection pooling
>   parameters in the default connection
>   strings. For more information please
>   refer to the following MSDN articles:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx
>
> If you wish to tune the Database
>   Connection Pooling, you can add
>   appropriate parameters to the
>   connection strings.

Second reply after I asked some more about it:

> Please see
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
>
> When a connection is first opened, a
>   connection pool is created based on an
>   exact matching algorithm that
>   associates the pool with the
>   connection string in the connection.
>   If MinPoolSize is either not specified
>   in the connection string or is
>   specified as zero, the connections in
>   the pool will be closed after a period
>   of inactivity. However, if the
>   specified MinPoolSize is greater than
>   zero, the connection pool is not
>   destroyed until the AppDomain is
>   unloaded and the process ends.
>   Maintenance of inactive or empty pools
>   involves minimal system overhead.
>
> Following connection strings
>   parameters can be applied.
>
> # Max Pool Size - specifies the
>   maximum size of your connection pool.
>   Default is 100. Most Web sites do not
>   use more than 40 connections under the
>   heaviest load but it depends on how
>   long your database operations take to
>   complete.   # Min Pool Size - initial
>   number of connections that will be
>   added to the pool upon its creation.
>   Default is zero; however, you may
>   chose to set this to a small number
>   such as 5 if your application needs
>   consistent response times even after
>   it was idle for hours. In this case
>   the first user requests won't have to
>   wait for those database connections to
>   establish.   # Pooling - controls if
>   your connection pooling on or off.
>   Default as you may've guessed is true.

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

The only mentioning about negative impacts I'm aware about is [this](http://vasilinenko.blogspot.com/2009/11/connection-pooling.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think I'll also try to ask Sitecore and see if they have some tips regarding connection pools. edit: I'll update this when I get an answer.